# Voice to Text conversion R

Tags: r, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way to convert user speech to text in realtime using R ? Just curious. Also it will be great if anybody could share some examples regarding what they have done in this domain.

Answer (score 6):

I'm just working on [`googleLanguageR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleLanguageR/index.html) that includes speech-to-text via the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)

Comment: this looks like a pre-recorded wave fine needs to be fed into the function. Can speech to text work in real time ?

Comment: Depends how real time you need it, an audio file can be recorded right before the API call. There is a Shiny app in the works that will work via a push button, recording the voice via JavaScript from your browser.

Comment: @MarkeD do I need a Google cloud platform account in advance to use this API?

Comment: Yes, it uses your authentication you get from there

Comment: Any non-commercial alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

As of 2023, it is possible to get speech-to-text transcription (and translation) using the "Whisper" Automatic Speech Recognition model.

The R package [`audio.whisper`](https://github.com/bnosac/audio.whisper) wraps the whisper.cpp C++ library, and basically makes it possible to transcribe text from within R. Once the model has been downloaded, the whole process can be conducted offline, without the need to call any external API.

The quality of the transcription is surprisingly good, including for major languages other than English. This is however not meant for "real time" transcriptions, as mentioned in the question, even if it probably can be adapted to work this way using one of the smaller models.

At the time of writing, one issue in particular should be mentioned for anyone who intends to try out `audio.whisper`:

- as mentioned [in the Readme](https://github.com/bnosac/audio.whisper#speed-of-transcribing), you should really consider installing (or reinstalling) the package using some of the suggested flags, as this *dramatically* improves performance

Searching on GitHub for "[whisper language:R](https://github.com/search?q=whisper%20language%3AR&type=repositories)" shows other R packages that rely on Whisper, but they mostly expect you to install `whisper` separately.

More complete, refined, or better documented R packages may appear, but these suggestions should put you on the right track to find a meaningful solution.